# Swift UITableView - Customizing first row on UITalbleVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a badge on the first row of a cell on a UITableView. My problem arises when the app is opened on a small device such as iPhone SE 2 where the UITableView needs to be scrolled down to display the last row. When I scroll down to the last row, it also has the badge that is only intended for the first row. It does not show up on the first scroll down but on multiple scroll up and down.

// willDisplay

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let news = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row]
    print("indexPath.section: \(indexPath.section) - indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row) - news \(news)")

    let hub = BadgeHub(view: cell)
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        hub.setCircleAtFrame(CGRect(x: 120, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25))
        hub.setCount(newsCount!)
    }
    else {
        hub.setCount(0)
        hub.checkZero()
    }
}
```

// cellForRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.cellID, for: indexPath) as? MenuViewCell {
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    var settingOptionName = ""
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: ("isDoneWithGuide")) == false {
        
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 12) && (self.isLogin) {
        settingOptionName = twoDimensionalArray[0].extraString[0]
    } else {
        settingOptionName = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row]
    }
    print("settingOptionName \(settingOptionName ?? "")")
    //cell.textLabel?.text = settingOptionName
    cell.setTitleLabel(text: settingOptionName)
    
    if showIndexPaths {
        //cell.textLabel?.text = "\(settingOptionName)   Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.setTitleLabel(text: "\(settingOptionName) Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)")
    }
    
    return cell
}

return UITableViewCell()
}
```

// UITableViewCell

```
class MenuViewCell : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!

func setTitleLabel(text : String) {
    self.titleLabel.text = text
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in `willDisplay`? You should do this in `cellForRow`.

Comment: Also, can you show what `BadgeHub` does?

Comment: @Sweeper I am doing this on `willDisplay` because `cellForRow` only displays the badge when the user displays the TableView for the second time. [BadgeHub](https://github.com/jogendra/BadgeHub)

Comment: You should definitely put the code that adds the badge in `cellForRow`. You should also keep an instance of `BadgeHub` in your cell class, and not create a new one every time, which is what causes this behaviour. Can you show your cell class, and your `cellForRow`?

Comment: @Sweeper updated the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a new `BadgeHub` like this:

```
let hub = BadgeHub(view: cell)
```

You're adding a new subview to `cell`, but it won't be visible if you set the badge number to 0.

Here comes the important point: when you scroll to the bottom, the table view does *not* create a *new* table view cell to be put there. Since the first table view cell is invisible now, it *reuses* the first cell as the cell that shows up at the bottom. This is what it means to `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`.

The first cell still has that badge, right? Now `willDisplay` gets called, and you add *another* invisible badge to it (you didn't do anything to the old badge on the cell). This is why the bottom cell also has a badge.

What you should do is to keep *one* instance of `BadgeHub` in the cell class:

```
lazy var badge = BadgeHub(view: self)
```

Now rather than creating a new `BadgeHub` every time, use this `badge` property that each of your cells have:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.badge.setCircleAtFrame(CGRect(x: 120, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25))
    cell.badge.setCount(newsCount!)
}
else {
    cell.badge.setCount(0)
    cell.badge.checkZero()
}
```

From my limited knowledge of how BadgeHub works, I think this would work in either `cellForRowAt` or `willDisplay`. `cellForRowAt` is normally where you give the cell the data to display, so I'd prefer there if I were you, but if it doesn't work there for some reason, you can also try `willDisplay`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I put it on `cellForRowAt`.